# JOIN LEFT with multiple conditions

Tags: mysql

I'm having following tables structure

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `review_author` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `client_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `IDX_37D99F0819EB6921` (`client_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=2110 ;
```

AND

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `brokers_comments` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `hb_broker_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `client_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `user_name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `user_email` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `state` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `text` varchar(3000) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `IDX_5365DFFB9FE55EF7` (`hb_broker_id`),
  KEY `IDX_5365DFFB19EB6921` (`client_id`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1583 ;
```

Before extracting value i did following query:

```
 INSERT INTO review_author (
                    name,
                    email,
                    client_id
                )
                SELECT
                    brokers_comments.user_name,
                    brokers_comments.user_email,
                    brokers_comments.client_id
                FROM brokers_comments
                LEFT JOIN review_author
                ON brokers_comments.user_name=review_author.name AND
                brokers_comments.user_email=review_author.email AND
                brokers_comments.client_id=review_author.client_id
                WHERE  review_author.id  IS NULL
```

Not in review_author should be all author from table `brokers_comments` and now i'm trying to get authors id using following query:

```
SELECT
    review_author.id
FROM brokers_comments
LEFT JOIN review_author
    ON brokers_comments.user_name=review_author.name AND
    brokers_comments.user_email=review_author.email AND
    brokers_comments.client_id=review_author.client_id
WHERE  review_author.id  IS NOT NULL
```

but i'm getting about 110 results from total 1531 records from table `brokers_comments`.

**UPDATE**

I couldn't manage to insert data in http://sqlfiddle.com/ so following link are dump for two tables *review_author* and *brokers_comments*.

*Again my issue is to transfer distinct columns(user_name, user_email, client_id) from table brokers_comments to table review_author and then select review_author.id based on relation name/email/client_id from both tables.*

http://wrttn.in/7ca325
http://wrttn.in/3a7885

Insert new author was wrong and made duplication. Below is new correct form.

```
INSERT INTO review_author (
                    name,
                    email,
                    client_id
                )
                SELECT  user_name, user_email, client_id
                FROM    brokers_comments AS broker
                WHERE   NOT EXISTS
                        (
                        SELECT  1
                        FROM    review_author AS author
                        WHERE   author.email = broker.user_email
                        )
                GROUP BY broker.user_email
```

P.S. I somebody will make a working online mysql database please put in comments so i could put it there.

**Resolved**
Only now i realised that user_email must be unique. Based on this i made following select statement:

```
SELECT 
    author.id
FROM  brokers_comments AS broker
LEFT JOIN review_author AS author
ON broker.user_email = author.email
```

Comment: first thing have you tried a `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM review_author` to make sure you have the correct number of records? second thing if you dont your insert query is wrong and you will need to change it. third thing can you post a sqlfiddle with some of the relevant information for us to test with?

Comment: Can you show a small set of sample data and expected results to describe what's not working?

Comment: @McAdam331 added in **update** part details.

Comment: @JohnRuddell check my **update** block.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you use excess fields in JOIN clause since client_id is a key, you need to join tables only on this field. Possible cause of that you getting not same number of records is different name/email for same client_id in those two tables. So, your two queries should be like this:

```
 INSERT INTO review_author (
                    name,
                    email,
                    client_id
                )
                SELECT
                    brokers_comments.user_name,
                    brokers_comments.user_email,
                    brokers_comments.client_id
                FROM brokers_comments
                LEFT JOIN review_author
                ON brokers_comments.client_id=review_author.client_id
                WHERE  review_author.id  IS NULL
```

and

```
SELECT
    review_author.id
FROM brokers_comments
LEFT JOIN review_author
    ON brokers_comments.client_id=review_author.client_id
WHERE  review_author.id  IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: It think your insert is same as mine i checked for select statement and it returns same row. Second select statement also returns incorrect number of rows.

Comment: The better you formulate your question, the closer answer is. Try to shorten input data keeping an error appearing: the goal should be about 5 records that reproduce original error. Then you could see the cause yourself, or else put this sample data here and get an answer very quickly

Comment: I've put in my `update` part links where are dumps for these two tables.